# Mod rewrite redirect direct access

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

1. I need redirect all users which call index.html file.
2. I need to use short link http://sites.com/111 but script takes files from fffolder/111.php
3. I need to redirect users who is want direct access to http://sites.com/fffolder/111.php to index.html

> ```
> Redirect 301 /index.html http://sites.com/ 
> RewriteEngine On 
> RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ fffolder/$1.php 
> RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ fffolder/$1.php  
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> #If file not foun redirect to index 
> RewriteRule .* index.html [PT]
>
> #Redirect direct access to all php files in fffolder 
> RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ index.html [R=301,L]
> ```

1 and 2 is working but 3 is not, how to write right syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC]

#Redirect direct access to all php files in fffolder 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /.+\.php [NC]
RewriteRule \.php$ /index.html [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ fffolder/$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#If file not foun redirect to index 
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

Comment: Only one i cant understand how this script knows where to redirect? in my example it be `Redirect 301 /index.html http://sites.com/ ` It must be redirect to another site

Comment: But how to redirect to another web page?

Comment: robots.txt now got error 500 `Internal Server Error` and not different URl but different site!!!

Comment: Yes all files which is exist got 500 error, `RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters, referer: http://sites.com/robots.txt`. And please edit your answer to show me where to put different domain to redirect in .htaccess

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96581/discussion-between-anubhava-and-dmitrij-holkin).